# Using Beyond Compare with Mercurial as the external diff tool to perform in-place directory comparison

Tags: mercurial, beyondcompare4

I have set up Beyond Compare 4 as the external diff tool for Mercurial. My mercurial.ini file looks like this:

```
[extensions]
extdiff =

[extdiff]
cmd.bc = C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe
opts.bc = /lro /solo
```

This seems to work well for the most part, but there's one improvement I would like to make to this setup, if possible. I can run `hg bc` and it will open Beyond Compare in Folder Compare mode, and it will show me the differences between my working directory and its parent changeset in the repository. However, both the left and right folders are located in temporary folders, for example:

```
c:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Temp\extdiff.o6grxl\foo
```

I would like to have the right-hand folder to be the actual working directory rather than a temporary directory.

If I run `hg bc file1.txt` against a single file, the right-hand side is pointed to the actual file in the working directory, as I would expect. It just doesn't work in the case when I am comparing the entire directory.

Is this possible? If so, how would I set that up?

Thanks!